# Multiple queries in documentdb-q-promises for Nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb

I want to render a page getting info for two different queries in CosmoDB using documentdb.

I have 2 queries:

```
var FirstQuery = {
  query: 'SELECT * FROM FactoryData',
};

var SecondQuery = {
  query: 'SELECT * FROM StoreData',
};
```

And have this to get the data

```
 docDbClient.queryDocuments(collLink, FirstQuery ).toArray(function (err, results) {
    value1 = results;
  });

docDbClient.queryDocuments(collLink, SecondQuery ).toArray(function (err, results) {
    value2 = results;
  });
```

then i want to render the view with those results but i cant get it rendering from  outise of this funcions.

```
res.render('view.html', {"value1" : value1 , "value2" : value2});
```

I know that this code will not work, but i was trying to implement promises and didn't know how to do it with documentdb-q-promises.

I already read a lot of documentation about Q promise but i dont get it.
Can someone explain to me how i can do it , I`m a beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirements,I followed the [npm doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/documentdb-q-promises) and test code on [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-node-q/blob/master/test/test.js) to test following code in my local express project. Please refer to it.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var DocumentClient = require('documentdb-q-promises').DocumentClientWrapper;

var host = 'https://***.documents.azure.com:443/';                    // Add your endpoint
var masterKey = '***'; // Add the massterkey of the endpoint

var client = new DocumentClient(host, {masterKey: masterKey});

var collLink1 = 'dbs/db/colls/import';
var FirstQuery = 'select c.id,c.name from c';
var collLink2 = 'dbs/db/colls/item';

var returnArray = [];

client.queryDocuments(collLink1, FirstQuery).toArrayAsync().
  then(function(response){
  console.log(response.feed);
  var map = {};
  map['value1'] = response.feed;
  returnArray.push(map);
  return client.queryDocuments(collLink2, FirstQuery).toArrayAsync()
})
.then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.feed);
  var map = {};
  map['value2'] = response.feed;
  returnArray.push(map); 
})
.fail(function(error) {
  console.log("An error occured", error);
});

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send(returnArray);
});

module.exports = router;
```

***Test Result:***

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks , Works perfect, now i understand very well about promises